# How to select date and time in a specific format in my react app?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, frontend

I am using react to build the front-end of my application. I need to capture the date and time in this format - [date_time_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zs76.png).
Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to study:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Javascript.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. That was informative. But I want to capture the date and time in the format specified in the image( link) of my question.